# angularjs nested accordion close-others not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, nested, accordion

I have a multi-level accordion going in angularJS using the "accordion" and "accordion-group" tags.  I'm using `close-others="false"` in the parent accordion, and `close-others="true"` in the nested accordion.

Instead of the expected behavior where the outer panel allows for multiple groups to expand and the inner panel only allows one, what I'm seeing is that both parent and child panels are allowing multiple groups to be open at once.

```
<accordion close-others="false">
  <!-- Outer Group #1 -->
  <accordion-group heading="Outer Group #1" ng-init="status.isOuterGroup1Open = true" 
       is-open="status.isOuterGroup1Open">
    <!-- Outer Content Here -->
  </accordion-group>

  <!-- Outer Group #2 -->
  <accordion-group heading="Outer Group #2" ng-init="status.isOuterGroup2Open = true" 
       is-open="status.isOuterGroup2Open">
    <accordian close-others="true">
      <!-- Inner Groups -->
      <accordion-group data-ng-repeat="outerItem in outerItems" 
           heading="{{outerItem.name}}">
        <div data-ng-repeat="innerItem in outerItem.children">
          <!-- Inner content here -->
          {{innerItem.name}}
        </div>
      </accordion-group>
    </accordian>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, inside the 'Outer Group #2' you have 'accordian' where it's supposed to be 'accordion'. I think that's the problem. Here's the code with the applied fix:

```
<accordion close-others="false">
  <!-- Outer Group #1 -->
  <accordion-group heading="Outer Group #1" ng-init="status.isOuterGroup1Open = true" 
       is-open="status.isOuterGroup1Open">
    <!-- Outer Content Here -->
  </accordion-group>

  <!-- Outer Group #2 -->
  <accordion-group heading="Outer Group #2" ng-init="status.isOuterGroup2Open = true" 
       is-open="status.isOuterGroup2Open">
    <accordian close-others="true">
      <!-- Inner Groups -->
      <accordion-group data-ng-repeat="outerItem in outerItems" 
           heading="{{outerItem.name}}">
        <div data-ng-repeat="innerItem in outerItem.children">
          <!-- Inner content here -->
          {{innerItem.name}}
        </div>
      </accordion-group>
    </accordian>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

If changing that doesn't fix the behavior, can you please post a plunker?